# Nginx TLS renegotiation

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls

Our webserver has recently failed a PCI compliance test due to existence of  "TLS Session Renegotiation Vulnerability" (CVE-2009-3555)
However I'm not sure whether those results are right. We're using nginx version 1.6.2, with openssl version 1.0.2.

As far as I know any kind of renegotiation is disabled in nginx since version 0.8.23. Qualsys SSL test results show that "SSL Secure Renegotiation" is enabled, but secure (and insecure) client initiated renegotiation are not.

Here's how an openssl session looks like :

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 192.0.2.1:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
<blah, blah, blah>
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
<blah blah>
GET / HTTP/1.1
R
RENEGOTIATING
140392261871432:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl  handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
```

What am I missing here? Is there a way to completely disable renegotiation in nginx?

Comment: Where is this server? You gave the [wrong IP address](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632).

Comment: You're right. Fixed.

Comment: Without posting your configuration and describing your setup, it's very hard to help you.